# get html textbox values as input to python file to print the returned value

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to get value from textbox on html webpage and print it in test.py file.

There are three files:

1. app.py
2. test.py
3. index.html

can someone please help?

## app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/", methods=["GET","POST"])
def get_provider():
    
    dp = request.form["provider"]
    dp_lower_case = dp.lower()

    return dp_lower_case


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ALMA PROCESS FLOW</title>
    </head>

<body>
<form method="POST">

<label style="position:relative; left:5px; bottom:15px;"> Data Provider:</label>
<input name ="provider"  type="text"">
<input type="submit" value="Generate"/>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

## test.py

```
from app import get_provider
provider = app.get_provider()

print(provider)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. When you don't specify a method for a route, it defaults to a `GET`. This means that your code currently has 2 handlers for when your home page is loaded.
2. Since your form is doing a post, drop the 'GET' in the methods list i.e. change

   `@app.route("/", methods=["GET","POST"])`

   to

   `@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])`
3. Better yet, you should combine everything i.e. change your code to

```
    @app.route("/", methods=["GET","POST"])
    def main():
        # When it is a GET
        if request.method == "GET":
            return render_template("index.html")
        
        # When it is a POST (user has submitted your form)
        elif request.method == "POST":
            dp = request.form["provider"]

            ''' Alternatively, you can use 
                
                dp = request.values.get("provider")

                I prefer it because this way, I can provide a 
                default value in case the form parameter has no value i.e

                dp = request.values.get("provider", "default provider")
            '''
            

            dp_lower_case = dp.lower()

            return dp_lower_case
```

Comment: Thanks this makes sense now, but how do I print the returned value in test.py file?

Comment: ```print(dp_lower_case)```